# Ajax call does not return json into website body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to return some JSON from an AJAX call and put it into the html body but I'm struggling with the below code. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: ({
      type: 'main'
    }),
    success: function(result) {
      $("#result").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='buttonJSONP'>Echo JSONP</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: in success console.log(result) and let me know what it shows

Comment: Look for errors in your console.

Comment: I see this is a GET URL , you sure this is a POST one

Comment: are you trying to get data or post data ?

Comment: I'm trying to return the json response @Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the request using a `get`, otherwise you need to look into your api for making `post` requests.

If it is a `post`, data doesn't look like this `({})`. Remove the parentheses and just use braces `{}`.

Using a `get` you need to move your `data` object into the url as well, because `get` requests don't have a body.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1?type=main',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      $("#result").html(Object.values(result).join(','));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='buttonJSONP'>Echo JSONP</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code -

1. as this is a post request you need to change your input as below also remove `(` and `)`

   `data: {
         "type": "main"
       }`
2. the API URL is also not correct for POST request, you will get 404 error even if the input is correct. The correct URL for POST will be as below -

`url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'`

Reference : [Fake JSON api documentation](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

So your complete code should be like below -

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
      "type": "main"
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#result").html(Object.values(result).join("-"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='buttonJSONP'>Echo JSONP</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

The response status will be HTTP 201.

Comment: 1. isn't necessary.

Comment: @KevinB which one ?

Comment: the one labeled 1.

Comment: @KevinB you need to remove the opening brackets right?

Comment: The brackets aren't necessary, but they don't impact the code in any way. they don't "need" to be removed

Comment: @KevinB I got unexpected character `(` at position 0 for json while making the ajax call ... is it related to this?

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask - why is the "1" removed and why does it break when you put it back?

Comment: @Jimmy maybe kevin will be able to answer that

Comment: @Jimmy if you check the other answer the `()` is removed also .. so why the downvote ... big mystery

Answer (score 0):

In the example above you're trying to post data into a Get url.

if you want to return json response from this url you must use GET instead of POST, your code should look like:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      $("#result").html(result.key);
    }
  });
});
```